# Reshape data from row to column in R

Tags: r, reshape

I am having a data in the following format.

```
Name    Value
282.08  27.91
284.07  19.08
286.06  18.8 
Name    Value
282.08  44.19
284.07  28.24
286.06  27.82
Name    Value
282.08  46.51
284.07  27.48
286.06  26.32
```

The column Name is having the same value. I want to have the data in the following format

```
Name    Value   Name    Value   Name    Value
282.08  27.91   282.08  44.19   282.08  46.51
284.07  19.08   284.07  28.24   284.07  27.48
286.06  18.8    286.06  27.82   286.06  26.32
```

How to do it in R?

Comment: try excel to manage your data and then save it. upload into R.

Comment: I have a huge dataset but for representation, I have kept only 3 rows with 3 dataset. The original dataset contains 121 such blocks with 512 rows each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, *but* in general, the output you are asking for should be avoided [duplicate column names and values of similar meaning (such as Names) in multiple columns]

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="Name    Value
282.08  27.91
284.07  19.08
286.06  18.8 
Name    Value
282.08  44.19
284.07  28.24
286.06  27.82
Name    Value
282.08  46.51
284.07  27.48
286.06  26.32", header=FALSE)
```

First split your data into a list

```
result <- split(df, cumsum(grepl("Name", df$V1)))
# $`1`
      # V1    V2
# 1   Name Value
# 2 282.08 27.91
# 3 284.07 19.08
# 4 286.06  18.8

# $`2`
      # V1    V2
# 5   Name Value
# 6 282.08 44.19
# 7 284.07 28.24
# 8 286.06 27.82

# $`3`
       # V1    V2
# 9    Name Value
# 10 282.08 46.51
# 11 284.07 27.48
# 12 286.06 26.32
```

Combine the list into a wide format using `Reduce("cbind", ...)`

```
ans <- Reduce("cbind", result)
      # V1    V2     V1    V2     V1    V2
# 1   Name Value   Name Value   Name Value
# 2 282.08 27.91 282.08 44.19 282.08 46.51
# 3 284.07 19.08 284.07 28.24 284.07 27.48
# 4 286.06  18.8 286.06 27.82 286.06 26.32
```

Make the first row your header

```
colnames(ans) <- ans[1,]
ans <- ans[-1,]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it has worked. Only the last two lines i.e. making the first row as the header are not working.

Comment: Do you obtain an error? Does it not provide the output you expect?

Comment: No, it is not showing any errors. But the column names are coming in some arbitrary numbers.I have saved the "ans" in .csv format and then removed the 1st row and it has provided me the desired results. Once again thanks a lot for your prompt help. It has saved my lot of time. Thank you very much.